# Ubuntu 20.04 Clean Install Mapping Wrong Characters

Tags: command-line, 20.04, keyboard

I've been wrestling with a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 for several days.

The latest issue / failure is that it's reading { and } as some other kind of squiggly character, and the keyboard types that same character, so it can't be corrected.

This happens not only in nano but also in the terminal.

The immediate consequence is that every.single.one of my installation scripts has a syntax error at the first instance of one of these.

Any ideas would be especially welcome.  I've got to get this installed so I can get back to work.

Comment: Where is `{` and `}` being read from? A keyboard, and SSH connection, or a file? 

Comment: Files and keyboard.  Again, existing install scripts with { and } substitute the squiggly characters in nano, are read / executed as if the squiggly characters were in the code, and typing { or } in either nano or the terminal results in one of the squiggly characters.

Comment: The behavior ceased once I got the GUI (gnome-session) running.  gdm and gnome-session, respectively, were booting to a black screen, possibly with or because of an Xorg freeze, so I was in a tty session (if I could get to one - the usual key combos often failed or took minutes to work).